# can you help me to realize client failover on oracle 12c?

Tags: oracle12c, failover, dataguard

I have 02 oracles and oracles vcpu servers on which are created respectively a primary BD (db_name = chicago and db_unique_name = chicago) and a standby BD (db_name = chicago and db_unique_name = boston). I created a service in the 02 servers with the utility srvctl:

```
srvctl add service -d "db_unique_name" -s CHICAGO_HA -l PRIMARY -q TRUE -e SELECT -m BASIC -z 150 -w 10
```

Then I added an entry in my tnsnames.ora file:

```
CHICAGO_HA =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (LOAD_BALANCE = off)
    (FAILOVER = on)
    (DESCRIPTION =
        (CONNECT_TIMEOUT = 10) (RETRY_COUNT = 3)
        (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = tcp) (HOST = 192.168.17.140) (PORT = 1522)))
        (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = chicago_ha))
    )
    (DESCRIPTION =
        (CONNECT_TIMEOUT = 10) (RETRY_COUNT = 3)
        (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = tcp) (HOST = 192.168.17.138) (PORT = 1522)))
        (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = chicago_ha))
    )
 )
```

I have a client on which i have opened a session :

```
sqlplus sys/*****@chicago_ha as sysdba
```

on primary host. i can query tables. but after switchover when i can't query tables because my session ends with errors like I am no longer connected.

Comment: This is a question you should be asking on [dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/). DBAs are more likely to be able to answer a question about configuring Dataguard than programmers.

Answer (score 1):

If I read it correctly, your setup has connect-time failover, but you are trying to use an already open connection to the now-closed instance?  You would need something like Application Continuity or Transparent Application Continuity for an existing connection to be moved to the other instance.   Check the Oracle white paper [Continuous Availability
Application Continuity for the Oracle Database](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/options/clustering/applicationcontinuity/adb-continuousavailability-5169724.pdf).

SQL*Plus generally isn't a great testing tool to mimic real-life apps that have connection pools and lots of users.

Comment: it seems to be that but the implementation. I don't always succeed. Please help me